# What is the difference between OIS Swap vs Basis Swap?

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap

What is the use of OIS Swap Curve vs. Basis Swap Curve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Basis swap is a broad category of swaps where you exchange one *floating rate* against another *floating rate*. Without knowing the specific rates involved it is difficult to say more.

An OIS Swap is an *Overnight Index Swap*, where you exchange a *fixed rate* against an average of the overnight rates for the tenor of the swap. For example, if the ON rate is Federal Funds Rate (FFR), then a 3 month OIS swap rate is essentially the market's guess of where the average overnight FFR will be during the next 3 months. (The overnight rate changes on a daily basis so it is of course a floating rate). The OIS curve plots these OIS rates against the tenor.